# Blender VSE Driver deleted when strip is copied or duplicated

Tags: video-sequence-editor, drivers

I need some insight or solution. In Blender VSE I have some transform strips with driver linked with another strip. Now I need to duplicate the transform strip with the driver. When I duplicate it, the driver is gone. How to resolve it or what is actually causing it? Is there any script or addon to deal with it?
Thanks in advance!

Observation: It creates new object and not instance while duplicating.

Comment: Yeah IIRC the VSE does not allow to instance strips any more as it was causing issues with shared F-curves. Duplicate only, which means that drivers go bye bye. Perhaps you can write a script that would copy drivers from one to another, not sure if the Sequencer Extras addon has such feature? https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Extra_Sequencer_Actions#Copy_Properties There is a Copy Properties function though

Comment: Sorry that addon is deprecated, you can grab a new one at Kino Raw tools for Blender. But it doesn't help. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The driver is not copied as the f-curve would have to be copied and the devs don't like to duplicate f-curves (as that gets quite messy).

Instead simply hover over the driver value in the first strip, right click and select "copy driver".
Go to the same value in the copied strip and right click then select "paste driver".

Remember that to see drivers update in the VSE you must either hit play or the button labeled "Update Sequencer" in the VSE timeline.

Comment: I wonder if it is because the strip driver belongs to the scene.  If you do a scene full copy the driver will be on the dupe strip.  (it would be one ugly workaround lol)... oh and do the debs have a ball?

Comment: Damn my autocorrect. IIRC Campbell said the data blocks got messy with f-curve dupes

Comment: TBH a "copy driver > paste to many strips" script seems like an easy solution?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I created one copy>paste driver for VSE Optical flare. If something like this is not there yet, will fork it. Seems easy if we can select the object and then active objects. Will give it a look.